Qooxdoo table: row or cell specific ToolTip
When I've got a Qooxdoo table and I want to have a tool tip that's valid for a full row (but it's different between each row): how can I create that?
A similar question is when I need a tool tip for a specific cell (actually all cells in a column, but of course with different content each)
Best would be when the tool tip content gets generated on the fly by the content of the row and a callback function (e.g. based on information in a hidden column).

If I get it right. You can create one tooltip for a table and then listen for some events like hover and change content of tooltip dynamically. The same approach for cells via events and listeners. The "cellTap" event.

That's an interesting approach. I'll try it.
